# How does one replace a word in a sentence when other words contain the same word within them

Tags: python

How does one replace a word in a sentence when other words contain the same word within them.

E.g.

```
sentence = "The tree must be bent while it was young"
```

How would you replace "be" in the sentence with "blah" without affecting the word "bent".

To be clear, you can't say just to replace the first instance of "be" because other sentences would be formed differently where the word being replaced would come after an instance of it being inside another word. E.g. "Bending be the key"

Comment: `re.sub(r'\bbe\b', '', sentence, re.I)`

Comment: That should include `'blah'` where there is the empty string `''` argument

Comment: if the word that is to be replaced was contained in a variable, how would you edit that to work
re.sub(r'\b+"word_to_be_replaced"+\b', '', sentence, re.I)?

Comment: `fr'\b{variable}\b'`

Comment: \b for word boundary https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters

Answer (score 0):

By only replacing "be" that has a space before it and a space after it, only the words "be" would be replaced, this can be achieved by using this simple line of code

`sentence.replace(" be ", " blah ")`

Input: "The tree must be bent while it was young"

Output: "The tree must blah bent while it was young"

Comment: but what if the word to be replaced was at the beginning or end of the sentence?

Comment: That matches none of these: "The tree will be, as foretold in legend, bent as it was to be."

Comment: Maybe you could add 2 separate tests to check for "be " and " be" at the start and end of the string.

Comment: If you want to account for the cases where a comma or period is after the "be", you can simply write a searching algorithm, but instead of checking if it is a space after "be", check whether the character after "be" is `in [",", ".", " "]`